# Looping union select function

Tags: postgresql

I have set of function query that usually I execute with union like as:

```
SELECT * FROM schedule_visit('2019-01-01')
UNION
SELECT * FROM schedule_visit('2019-01-02')
UNION
SELECT * FROM schedule_visit('2019-01-03') 
...
```

How can I execute that function for examaple from ('2019-01-01') until ('2019-12-31') with looping in Postgres.

Comment: What about pass second parameter to be endDate?

Answer (score 1):

If the arguments can be generated as series:

```
select f.*
from generate_series('2019-01-01'::timestamp, '2019-01-31', '1 day') as g(d)
cross join schedule_visit(d::date) as f
```

otherwise:

```
select f.*
from (
    values
        ('2019-01-01'),
        ('2019-01-03'),
        ('2019-01-06'),
        ('2019-01-15')
    ) as v(d)
cross join schedule_visit(d::date) as f
```